# Illegal assignment from Boolean to Casecomments__c

Tags: unit-test, class

Please help me to get the test class for below class.

```
public inherited sharing class BI_QuickCloseCompController {
    private static final String CLASS_NAME='BI_QuickCloseCompController';
    private static final String METHOD_NAME='closeSR';
    private static final String CLOSED='Closed';

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Integer getCaseCommentsCount(string caseId){
        return string.isNotBlank(caseId)? [SELECT count() from Casecomments__c where Case_Id__c=:caseId]:0;
    }
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Boolean closeSR(String caseId){
        try{
            if(string.isNotBlank(caseId)){
                string errorMessage='';
                Case sr=new Case(id=caseId,status=CLOSED,SR_Closed_Automatically__c=true);
                if(Schema.SobjectType.Case.isUpdateable()){
                    Database.saveResult saveResultData=Database.update(sr,false);
                    if(saveResultData.isSuccess())
                        return true;
                    else{
                        for(Database.error err:saveResultData.getErrors()){
                            errorMessage=err.getMessage();
                        }
                        UTIL_SLB.throwAuraHandledException(errorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception ecptnWhileClosingSR){
            UTIL_SLB.throwAuraHandledException(ecptnWhileClosingSR.getMessage());
            UTIL_SLB.logHandledException(ecptnWhileClosingSR,BI_UTIL_Constants.Business_Insurance,CLASS_NAME,METHOD_NAME,null,LoggingLevel.ERROR);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static boolean saveComment(String caseId,boolean privateFlag,boolean policyFlag, boolean billingFlag, String comment){
        try{
            if(string.isNotBlank(caseId) && string.isNotBlank(comment)){
                String DestionationSystem=UTIL_Common_Constants.EMPTY_VALUE;
                DestionationSystem+=(policyFlag && billingFlag) ? (BI_UTIL_Constants.BI_Target_PolicySystem +UTIL_Common_Constants.SemiColon+ BI_UTIL_Constants.BI_Target_BillingSystem):(policyFlag?BI_UTIL_Constants.BI_Target_PolicySystem:(billingFlag?BI_UTIL_Constants.BI_Target_BillingSystem:UTIL_Common_Constants.EMPTY_VALUE));
                    Casecomments__c casComment = new Casecomments__c(Case_Id__c = caseId,Private__c = privateFlag,Comments__c = comment,Destination_System__c = DestionationSystem) ;
                insert casComment;
                return true;
            }
        }catch(DmlException dmlExcp){UTIL_SLB.extractDMLExcpMsgNThrowAuraHandledException(dmlExcp);}
        return false;
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest(seeAllData = false)
public class BI_QuickCloseCompControllerTest {
    @testsetup
    static void testData() {
        Case cse = new Case(status='New');
        insert cse;
        Casecomments__c cComments1 = new Casecomments__c();
        cComments1.Comments__c = 'Test123';
        cComments1.Destination_System__c = 'Policy System';
        cComments1.Private__c = true;
        cComments1.Case_Id__c =  cse.Id;
        insert cComments1;

    }
    static testMethod void testSaveCasecomments(){
        List<Casecomments__c> caseComments=[SELECT id,Comments__c,Private__c,Destination_System__c,Case_Id__c FROM Casecomments__c LIMIT 1 ];
        Boolean policySys,billingSys;
        if(string.isNotBlank(caseComments[0].Destination_System__c)){
            policySys=caseComments[0].Destination_System__c.contains('Policy System')?true:false;
            billingSys=caseComments[0].Destination_System__c.contains('Billing System')?true:false;
        }
        caseComments[0].Comments__c+='Update Comment';   
        Casecomments__c updatedComment =BI_QuickCloseCompController.saveComment(caseComments[0].Case_Id__c,caseComments[0].Private__c,policySys,billingSys,caseComments[0].Comments__c);
        System.assertEquals(updatedComment.Private__c, True);
        Casecomments__c upsertedComment =BI_QuickCloseCompController.saveComment(caseComments[0].Case_Id__c,caseComments[0].Private__c,policySys,billingSys,updatedComment.Comments__c+'Upserted Comment'); 
        System.assertEquals(upsertedComment.Private__c,True);
    } 

}
```

getting the error Illegal assignment from Boolean to Casecomments__c

Please help me to write the test class for this.

Answer (score 0):

this problem arises because you are trying to assign a `CaseComments__c` variable a boolean value:

```
Casecomments__c updatedComment =BI_QuickCloseCompController.saveComment();
Casecomments__c upsertedComment =BI_QuickCloseCompController.saveComment();
```

If you check out your `saveComment()` method, you will see that it's return value is a boolean and not `Casecomments__c`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I can see below after that 'Variable does not exist: Comments__c'